# 3d surface plot to be generated from diagonal eigenvalues (Matlab error)

Tags: matlab

I have the following loop: I have solved for the eigenvalues but wish to generate a surface plot of e,r, and c(i,j) for each successive iteration of my loop. I know each input is a scalar but I am able to generate a 3 by 3 diagonal matrix D. How can I do a surface plot?
Here is my code: ( I am not sure how to upload matlab code so here is the image)

[image]

```
L=1.25;            
k=1.5;             
m=0.2;              
M=45;                          
p=0.625;            
Ig=(1/12)*M*L^(2);

for i=1:3

for j=1:3

ee(i)=0.1 + i.*0.1;
er(j)=0.1+j.*0.1;

e=ee(i);r=er(j);
Q=(((m*(r.^(2))*(L^(2))*k)./e)-M.*p.*k-m.*k.*L.*r.^(2));
N=(M*(p^(2))+Ig+(m.*(r.^(2)).*(L^(2)))/4*e.^(2));
J=-(m.*(r.^(2))*(k^(2))*L)./e; 
y=-k./e;
x=(L./e)-1;
A=[0,1,0; 0,Q./N,J./N;0,x,y];
[V,D] = eig(A);
c(i,j)=D(2,2);
u(i,j)=D(3,3)

end
end
surf(e,r,c)
```

Comment: paste your code as text and not as an image: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216464/how-to-insert-code-properly-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Regardless of the loop how do I generate a surface plot using the specified eigenvalues from matrix D and the quantities e and r?

Comment: check the `surf` required input dimensions. you're trying to plot a 3x3 Z matrix against x and y scalars. if you will do `surf(ee,er,c)` it will plot the surface (not sure if the desired one however).